# Made button form and in js file its not triggering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I completed this form inside bootstrap table earlier it was working but after I added just option. Its not even triggering JS file code with only alert also while other buttons of different forms are triggering all these are in same JS file.

Here is form code : (Ps since using PHP called this file in index.php file this is other php file)

```
 <div id="sixth-part" class=tabcontent>  
       <h2 class="main-headings">Painting</h2>
       <form action="Controller/painting.php" method="POST" id="painting-form">
       <table data-toggle="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th colspan=4>Checkpoints and Record</th>
                <th>Check</th>
                <th>Incharge</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="display: none">
                    <td>
                    <p id="pumpserialno7"><?php echo("$model");?></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                <td>33</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                    <label for="application-record" >Application record sheet filled and maintained</label>
                    </div>            
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>   
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check-34">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $login_session; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>34</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                    <label for="blasting-record" >Blasting record sheet available</label>
                    </div>            
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>   
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check-35">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $login_session; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                    <label for="sample-plates" >Sample plates available with proper traceability to batch of painting</label>
                    </div>            
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>   
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check-36">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $login_session; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>36</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                    <label for="visual-inspection" >Visual Inspection & DFT</label>
                    </div>            
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>   
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check-37">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $login_session; ?></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
                <td>37</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
                <label for="antirush-coating" >Antirust Coating</label>
                <select name="antirush-coating" id="antirushcoating">
                    <option value="Phenolic Varnish">Phenolic Varnish</option>
                    <option value="Redoxide">Redoxide</option>
                    <option value="Others">Others</option>
                </select>
                </div>            
                </td>
                <td colspan=1>   
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check-37-a">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $login_session; ?></td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>         
                <td colspan=6 style="text-align:center">
                <button style="width:700px" type="submit" id="painting" class="btn btn-primary painting-btn">Freeze</button></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td><p id="eid6"><?php echo $login_session; ?></p></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
<div id='response6'></div>
```

Here is JS code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#painting-form').submit(function(event) {
     alert("hi");
 var formData = {
      pumpserialno: $("#pumpserialno7").text(),
      antirushcoating: $("#antirushcoating").val(),
      eid:$("#eid6").text()

    }

     $.ajax({
          type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
          url         : 'Controller/painting.php', // the url where we want to POST
          data        : formData, // our data object
          dataType    : 'text', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
          encode          : true,
          success: function( data ) {
            $("#response6").html(data);
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          // check status && error
          },
          })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data);
             $('#myModal').modal('show');

        });
       event.preventDefault();
   //   alert($("#visual-inspection").val());
```

});
});

Here is Index file code :  (Called this file in this way)

```
include("Parts/Insert/part6.php");
```

Comment: Did you check for errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes no errors related to JS file

Comment: try to use $("#painting").click(callbackFunc()); instead

Comment: Unrelated, fyi: the `for` attribute on labels should point to an existing `id` attribute

Comment: @masoud CallbackFunc is not defined

Comment: @brombeer sure will fix this

Comment: @SaadGhojaria I know it, I mean you can use callbackFunc on this case; apart from this, because `$('#painting-form')` is array of elements if you use `$('#painting-form')[0]` it should correctly work.

Comment: Updated JS code this what i actually wanted to do in JS but im wondering even button click function is not working so I was testing with alert.

Comment: alert($('#painting-form')[0]);
This is giving undefined I added this in document ready function.

Comment: It got solved apparently some table tags of my previous form was opened and never closed so it was making malfunctioning . Thankyou @brombeer for your time and efforts.